# CSS animation: center absolute div diagonally

Tags: css, animation, centering, absolute, diagonal

I have 4 square divs absolute positioned in each corner on the page. I need to animate them to ease into the center to form a circle. I am having a rough time trying to figure out how you would move them diagonally to the center. I have the code below for my html and css. So far I have them all the colors they are suppose to be and I have them set to transition with ease into a border-radius of 50% for one side on each. That way when they move diagonally to the center they can join together to eventually form into a circle. ***The main issue is just figuring out how to have them ease diagonally into the center.*** (I am only aloud to use css for this.)I also have what I have tried to accomplish this with in comments in the css code.

```
<body>
<div class="square_one"></div>

<div class="square_two"></div>

<div class="square_three"></div>

<div class="square_four"></div>
</body>


CSS
/* Layout */
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-name: squareCircle;
  animation-duration: 5s;


animation-delay: 1s;
  /* animation-iteration-count: infinite; */
  transition: background-color 5s ease;
}

@keyframes squareCircle {
  to {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

.square_one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation-name: squareOne;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transition: border-bottom-right ease 4s;
  /* transition: translate 4s; */
  /* transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
  
}

@keyframes squareOne {
  to {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    /* transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
  }
}

.square_two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0%;
  animation-name: squareTwo;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transition: border-bottom-left ease 0.5s;
}

@keyframes squareTwo {
  to {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  }
}

.square_three {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0;
  animation-name: squareThree;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transition: border-top-right ease 0.5s;
}

@keyframes squareThree {
  to {
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  }
}

.square_four {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  animation-name: squareFour;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transition: border-top-left-radius ease 5s;
}

@keyframes squareFour {
  to {
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  }
}

/* Block */

.square_one {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.square_two {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.square_three {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.square_four {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking to accomplish? :)

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-name: squareCircle;
  animation-duration: 5s;

animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: 1s;
  /* animation-iteration-count: infinite; */
  transition: background-color 5s ease;
}

@keyframes squareCircle {
  to {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

.square_one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation-name: squareOne;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transition: border-bottom-right, top, left ease 4s;
  /* transition: translate 4s; */
  
}

@keyframes squareOne {
  to {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
  }
}

.square_two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0%;
  animation-name: squareTwo;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transition: border-bottom-left, top, right ease 0.5s;
}

@keyframes squareTwo {
  to {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
  }
}

.square_three {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0;
  animation-name: squareThree;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transition: border-top-right, bottom, left ease 0.5s;
}

@keyframes squareThree {
  to {
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  }
}

.square_four {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  animation-name: squareFour;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transition: border-top-left-radius, bottom, right ease 5s;
}

@keyframes squareFour {
  to {
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  }
}

/* Block */

.square_one {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.square_two {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.square_three {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.square_four {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="square_one"></div>

<div class="square_two"></div>

<div class="square_three"></div>

<div class="square_four"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I actually just got it to work and was about to put up the code I used, incase anyone else has issues with this sort of thing. But it is pretty much on point with what you just answered with. Like almost identical, except my mentor had me delete all my code and use shorthands and ect to make my life easier, luckily. Really need to get in the habit of that, but I am learning. Lol. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS I wound up with to get the results I needed. Hopefully we are/were able to help anyone with the same or similar issue now or even in the future.

```
/*Universal*/
.square_one,
.square_two,
.square_three,
.square_four {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.square_one:hover,
.square_two:hover,
.square_three:hover,
.square_four:hover {
  transition: border 0.25s linear;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
/*Individual*/
.square_one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: coral;
  animation: circle1 3s linear 1 forwards;
}

.square_two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  animation: circle2 3s linear 1 forwards;
}

.square_three {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: lightgreen;
  animation: circle3 3s linear 1 forwards;
}

.square_four {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  animation: circle4 3s linear 1 forwards;
}
/*Animation*/
@keyframes circle1 {
  0% {
    position: absolute;
  }
  100% {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 0 0 100px 0;
  }
}
@keyframes circle2 {
  0% {
    position: absolute;
  }
  100% {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 100px;
  }
}
@keyframes circle3 {
  0% {
    position: absolute;
  }
  100% {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 0 100px 0 0;
  }
}
@keyframes circle4 {
  0% {
    position: absolute;
  }
  100% {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
  }
}
```